# Setup VirtualBox VM to access the internet but not the local network

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I want my VM:

- To access the internet
- but not to access the local network (the whole network of your home/company, not a VM internal network)

I think there's no special setting like "Host-only"/"NAT"/... but maybe there is a way to do that with "bridge", or maybe with some extra setup.

If you know a ay to do that, Thank you.

Comment: Network and connectivity is just that. You need to go to all the other machines and block the VM.

Comment: Maybe bridging the adapter in which case it gets an IP on the same range as the router; then configuring the VM firewall so that traffic in that subnet is only allowed to the DGW, rest of the network is blocked?